# Many to many model connection

Tags: django, django-models

So i have following models: Session, Rider.

Basically now i want to have results where rider was placed in each session so basically its M:N connection (each rider is in many sessions, and each session have many riders).

Now should i make new model called something like SessionResult? and place both foreign keys from Session and Rider and add a position field to this midtable? Or what is your recommendation?

Here is model:

```
class Rider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=100, db_index=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last name'), max_length=100, db_index=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(_('Rider number'))
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    country = CountryField()
    birthday = models.DateField(_('Birthday'))
    birth_place = models.CharField(_('Birth place'), max_length=100)
    weight = models.IntegerField(_('Weight'))
    height = models.IntegerField(_('Height'))
    info = models.TextField(_('Info'))

class Session(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, db_index=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Start time'))
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(_('End time'))
```

so something like this?

```
class SessionResult(models.Model):
    rider = models.ForeignKey(Rider)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    time = models.TimeField()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is great and Django has a specific feature to handle that nicely.
you can use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) with the `through` attribute

In your case that could look like:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    ... other fields ...
    riders = models.ManyToManyField(
        Rider,
        through='SessionResult',
    )
```

using your `SessionResult`.

You can place the ManyToMany field on the Rider model instead of Session if it makes more sense for you. Get a look at the Django documentation I linked, it has very useful details.